# strange android performance issue

Tags: android, performance

I'm having a strange issue with an Android game I'm making. It's a 2d action puzzler; the sprites and background are simple opaque images, but need to move quickly and smoothly. I have been experiencing general frame rate issues however, and this particular issue is quite confusing to me though.

The problem is that I can start my game (on the hardware, a Nexus 7) and have it run at a frame rate of at least 60fps, then close it and start it back up and it will run at 30-45. Repeating this process, the game usually runs with the slower framerate, but runs perfectly smoothly on every 4th (or so) attempt.

I am new to Android and programming in general, so Im wondering if anyone has a guess as to what could be causing this performance discrepancy on repeated runs? I can edit to include some code if it's helpful, but this seems more theoretical and Im not sure what would be relevant to post.

Thanks.

EDIT:

Here's my onCreate code:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.os.PowerManager.WakeLock;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import com.jag.framework.Audio;
import com.jag.framework.FileIO;
import com.jag.framework.Game;
import com.jag.framework.Graphics;
import com.jag.framework.Input;
import com.jag.framework.Screen;

public abstract class AndroidGame extends Activity implements Game {
    AndroidFastRenderView renderView;
    Graphics graphics;
    Audio audio;
    Input input;
    FileIO fileIO;
    Screen screen;
    WakeLock wakeLock;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        boolean isPortrait = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;
        int frameBufferWidth = isPortrait ? 800: 1200;
        int frameBufferHeight = isPortrait ? 1200: 800;
        Bitmap frameBuffer = Bitmap.createBitmap(frameBufferWidth,
                frameBufferHeight, Config.RGB_565);

        float scaleX = (float) frameBufferWidth
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
        float scaleY = (float) frameBufferHeight
                / getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

        renderView = new AndroidFastRenderView(this, frameBuffer);
        graphics = new AndroidGraphics(getAssets(), frameBuffer);
        fileIO = new AndroidFileIO(this);
        audio = new AndroidAudio(this);
        input = new AndroidInput(this, renderView, scaleX, scaleY);
        screen = getInitScreen();
        setContentView(renderView);

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyGame");
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        wakeLock.acquire();
        screen.resume();
        renderView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wakeLock.release();
        renderView.pause();
        screen.pause();

        if (isFinishing())
            screen.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public Input getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    @Override
    public FileIO getFileIO() {
        return fileIO;
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics getGraphics() {
        return graphics;
    }

    @Override
    public Audio getAudio() {
        return audio;
    }

    @Override
    public void setScreen(Screen screen) {
        if (screen == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Screen must not be null");

        this.screen.pause();
        this.screen.dispose();
        screen.resume();
        screen.update(0);
        this.screen = screen;
    }

    public Screen getCurrentScreen() {

        return screen;
    }
}
```

and here's my main code:

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Paint.Style;
import android.graphics.Rect;


import com.jag.framework.Game;
import com.jag.framework.Graphics;
import com.jag.framework.Image;

import com.jag.framework.Input.TouchEvent;
import com.jag.framework.Screen;

public class GameScreen extends Screen {
    enum GameState {
        Ready, Running, Paused, GameOver    
    }

    GameState state = GameState.Ready;



    // Variable Setup
    private static Scene scene;
    public static int screenheight;

    private ArrayList<Pieces> pieces;

    //lanes:
    int lane;

    Paint paint, paint2;
    Rect rect;
    Image fore, rings1, rings2, base1, base2;
    boolean recent, freeze, touch, pospressed, negpressed, wrongbutton;
    int timepassed, difficulty, recentinterval, score;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    Canvas canvas2;
    Rect foreg;
    InputStream in;
    AssetManager assets;


    public GameScreen(Game game) {
        super(game);

        // Initialize game objects here
        scene = new Scene(600);
        screenheight = game.getGraphics().getHeight();
        pieces = new ArrayList<Pieces>();

        lane = 100;
        recent = true;
        Pieces p3 = new Pieces(lane, 940, true);    
        pieces.add(p3);

        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);        
        paint2 = new Paint();
        paint2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint2.setStyle(Style.FILL);
        difficulty = 50;
        recentinterval = 30;
        timepassed = 0;
        freeze = false;
        fore = Assets.block;
        rings1 = Assets.ringswhite;
        rings2 = Assets.ringsblack;
        base1 = Assets.basewhite;
        base2 = Assets.baseblack;
        wrongbutton = false;
        score = 0;


    }

    @Override
    public void update(float deltaTime) {
        List<TouchEvent> touchEvents = game.getInput().getTouchEvents();

        // We have four separate update methods in this example.
        // Depending on the state of the game, we call different update methods.
        // Refer to Unit 3's code. We did a similar thing without separating the
        // update methods.

        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            updateReady(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            updateRunning(touchEvents, deltaTime);
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            updatePaused(touchEvents);
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            updateGameOver(touchEvents);
    }

    private void updateReady(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {

        // This example starts with a "Ready" screen.
        // When the user touches the screen, the game begins. 
        // state now becomes GameState.Running.
        // Now the updateRunning() method will be called!

        if (touchEvents.size() > 0) {

            game.getGraphics().clearScreen(Color.BLACK);            
            state = GameState.Running;
            Assets.theme.stop();
        }

    }

    private void updateRunning(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents, float deltaTime) {
        // 1. All touch input is handled here:
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if ((event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DRAGGED || event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN) && event.y <= 1000) {
                touch = true;
                scene.setLine(event.x);
            }   

            //POSITIVE BUTTON
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN && ((0 < event.x) && (event.x < 250)) && event.y > 1000) {
                pospressed = true;
            }

            //NEGATIVE BUTTON
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_DOWN && ((550 < event.x) && (event.x < 800)) && event.y > 1000) {
                negpressed = true;
            }

            //ACTIVATES ALERT (reduce score)
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                touch = false;
                pospressed = false;
                negpressed = false;
            }   
        }

        // 2. Check miscellaneous events like death:
        //        if (livesLeft == 0) {
        //            state = GameState.GameOver;
        //        }
        // 3. Call individual update() methods here.
        // This is where all the game updates happen.
        // For example, robot.update();

        if (!freeze){
            timepassed += 1;
            if ((timepassed % recentinterval) == 0){
                recent = false;
            }
        }

        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(difficulty);
        int randomInt2 = randomGenerator.nextInt(7);
        boolean randomBool = randomGenerator.nextBoolean();
        int chanceOfNewPiece = 8; 

        if ((randomInt < chanceOfNewPiece)&&!recent) {
            Pieces p = new Pieces((randomInt2+1)*lane, 940, randomBool);
            pieces.add(p);
            recent = true;
        }

        Iterator<Pieces> it = pieces.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Pieces p = it.next();
            if (p.isVisible()&&!p.wayback&&!freeze)
                p.update();
            else if (p.isVisible()&&!p.wayback&&freeze){
                p.still();
            }
            else if (p.wayback && pospressed){
                if (score > 10){
                    score -= 10;
                }
                if (score <= 10){
                    score = 0;
                }
                if (p.type){
                    it.remove();
                    freeze = false;
                    pospressed = false;
                    Assets.click.play(100);
                }
                if (!p.type){
                    freeze = false;
                    pospressed = false;
                    wrongbutton = true;
                }
            }
            else if (p.wayback && negpressed){
                if (score > 10){
                    score -= 10;
                }
                if (score <= 10){
                    score = 0;
                }
                if (p.type){
                    freeze = false;
                    negpressed = false;
                    wrongbutton = true;
                }
                if (!p.type){
                    it.remove();
                    freeze = false;
                    negpressed = false;
                    Assets.click.play(100);
                }

            }
            else if (p.isVisible() && p.wayback && wrongbutton){
                p.updateback();
            }           
            else if (p.isVisible()&&p.wayback){
                p.updateback();
                freeze = true;
            }

            else if (p.y < 10){
                score += 1;
                it.remove();
                freeze = false;
                wrongbutton = false;
            }

            else {
                //              if (p.y > screenheight-281){
                //                  game.getGraphics().clearScreen(Color.BLACK);
                //                  state = GameState.GameOver;
                //              }
                score = 0;
                it.remove();
                freeze = false;
                wrongbutton = false;
            }
        }

        //      if (pieces.size() == 0) {
        //
        //          game.getGraphics().clearScreen(Color.BLACK);
        //          state = GameState.GameOver;
        //      }

    }

    private void updatePaused(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {
                state = GameState.Running;
                Assets.theme.stop();
            }
        }
    }

    private void updateGameOver(List<TouchEvent> touchEvents) {
        int len = touchEvents.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            TouchEvent event = touchEvents.get(i);
            if (event.type == TouchEvent.TOUCH_UP) {

                nullify();
                game.setScreen(new MainMenuScreen(game));
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void paint(float deltaTime) {

        //Debug.startMethodTracing();
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        // draw the game elements
        if (state == GameState.Running){

            int fingerx = scene.getLine();
            g.drawRect(fingerx, 0, g.getWidth(), 1200, Color.BLACK);



            g.drawRect(0, 0, fingerx, 1200, Color.WHITE);

            if (touch == false){
                g.drawRect(250, 1000, 302, 205, Color.RED);
            }
            g.drawScaledImage(base1, fingerx, 955, g.getWidth()-fingerx, 
                    base2.getHeight(), fingerx, 0, g.getWidth()-fingerx, base2.getHeight());

            g.drawScaledImage(base2, 0, 955, fingerx, base2.getHeight(), 0, 0, fingerx, base2.getHeight());

            g.drawString(String.valueOf(score),
                    350, 1075, paint);  

            ////g.drawImage(back, 0, 0);
            //          g.drawScaledImage(Assets.fore, fingerx, 0, g.getWidth()-fingerx, 
            //                  Assets.fore.getHeight(), fingerx, 0, g.getWidth()-fingerx, Assets.fore.getHeight());        
            ////g.drawImage(Assets.topwhite, 0, 0);
            //g.saveCanvas();
            //g.drawTransRect(0, 0, fingerx, g.getHeight());
            ////g.drawImage(fore, 0, 0);            
            //g.drawImage(base2, 0, 955);           
            //          g.drawScaledImage(Assets.back, 0, 0, fingerx, Assets.back.getHeight(), 0, 0, fingerx, base2.getHeight());               
            //          g.drawScaledImage(base2, fingerx, 955, g.getWidth()-fingerx, base2.getHeight(), 
            //          fingerx, 0, g.getWidth()-fingerx, base2.getHeight());
            //g.drawCropped(base2);
            ////g.drawImage(rings2, 0, 950);            
            //g.restoreCanvas();    


            for (Pieces p : pieces){

                if (p.type == true)
                    g.drawImage(Assets.pos, (p.x - 40), p.y);

                if (p.type == false){
                    g.drawImage(Assets.neg, (p.x - 40), p.y);
                }
            }
        }

        // draw the UI
        if (state == GameState.Ready)
            drawReadyUI();
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            drawRunningUI();
        if (state == GameState.Paused)
            drawPausedUI();
        if (state == GameState.GameOver)
            drawGameOverUI();

        //Debug.stopMethodTracing();
    }
    private void nullify() {

        // Set all variables to null. You will be recreating them in the
        // constructor.
        paint = null;
        scene = null;
        pieces = null;  
        scene = null;
        pieces = null;      
        paint2 = null;
        Assets.theme = null;
        Assets.click = null;
        // Call garbage collector to clean up memory.
        System.gc();
    }

    private void drawReadyUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();

        g.drawARGB(155, 0, 0, 0);
        g.drawString("TOUCH THE SCREEN YA DUMMY",
                400, 300, paint);       
    }

    private void drawRunningUI() {
        //Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
    }

    private void drawPausedUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        // Darken the entire screen so you can display the Paused screen.
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 801, 1281, Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("HEY GUY IT'S PAUSED", 640, 300, paint);
    }

    private void drawGameOverUI() {
        Graphics g = game.getGraphics();
        g.drawRect(0, 0, 1281, 801, Color.BLACK);
        g.drawString("GAME OVER BRO", 640, 300, paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
        if (state == GameState.Running)
            System.gc();
        state = GameState.Paused;


    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void backButton() {
        pause();
    }

    public static Scene getScene(){
        return scene;
    }

    public void setScore(int i){
        score += i;
    }


}
```

I realize this is a bit of a mess; it's the first thing I've coded. The framework is from kilobolt.com. Let me know if there are other classes/ methods I should include.

Comment: How are you closing the game? Your old game activity might still be running in the background.

Comment: I'm hitting the Android "window" button (bottom-right), then sliding the window to get rid of it. I assume that Android terminates the process when I do that, but maybe there is more to it.

Comment: It [doesn't necessarily kill it immediately](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/20663). However, whether it works like that or not, users **will** expect it to work right from a normal pause/resume. Does it? Either way, show us some code. Lifecycle code especially.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I've added some of the program above. The game works fine from pause/resume. Whenever I start the game, if the framerate is slow, it stays that way no matter what I do. Same case when it's fast. Pausing, resuming, leaving the game and starting other programs etc have no effect on the framerate. The only thing that effects it (that I can tell) is when I close the program and restart it. When I do that, about 20% of the time the framerate is fine. Very strange.

Comment: Have a look at the engine you are using, does it need to release some resources in `onDestroy` method?

Comment: I don't think onDestroy is ever called (the framework does not include that method). I was under the impression that onDestroy does not actually need to be called necessarily?